# How to generate x.509 certificate by the Java keytool command-line interface

Tags: java, resteasy, bouncycastle

I am using RESTEasy encryption. For that I have to generate x.509 certificate by the Java 'keytool' command-line interface.

Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the command to generate self signed certificates. All in one line

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks 
        -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

When you run this command, it will ask you for the details of the signatory. These will be the details of your organization. Provide all the details and it will create a new self signed certificate in keystore `keystore` for you.

**NOTE:** When it ask for your first and last name, give the domain name of the server which will be the entry point for your users. i.e. www.myserver.com

If you already have a keystore then you can use your existing keystore to add new certificate otherwise this command will create the keystore `keystore.jks` with the `password` and add the certificate to the new keystore. Note that if you already have a keystore then you need to provide the password of the existing keystore in `-storepass` parameter of this command.

For more details, see the keytool man page:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html

Here you will find details of all the available options you can use with the keytool command.

Comment: additionally you can provide the details of the signatory by the command line option "-dname o=foo,ou=bar,c=XY,cn=foobar".

Comment: In addition, you can find examples here : https://lightbend.github.io/ssl-config/CertificateGeneration.html#generating-x-509-certificates